# c++ Class Members Returning Odd values

Tags: c++, oop

I will start this out by saying c++ is my first programming language and I am a beginner at best. And I am sure this has some sort of obvious answer.

But for some reason this simple program with a single custom class is returning very odd values from the Get functions that are calling the private members of the one custom class.

The program is separated into three file as follows.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <string>
 #include <cctype>
 #include "Shapes.h"

 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
     double test=20.0;
     Cube D(test);
     cout<< D.GetSA()<<endl<<D.GetSide();
     return 0;
 }
```

then as header files for the one Classes called `Shapes.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;


class Cube 
{
  public:
    Cube();
    Cube(double);
    double GetSA() const;
    double GetSide() const;

  private:
    double SA;
    double V;
    double Side;
};
```

And another file Called `Shapes.cpp` that contains the Constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include "Shapes.h"

Cube::Cube() 
{
    V=0.0;
    SA=0.0;
    Side=0.0
}

Cube::Cube(double Side2)
{
    Side=Side2;
}

double Cube::GetSA() const
{
    return SA;
}

double Cube::GetSide() const
{
    return Side;
}
```

for some reason when this program is run it returns a value of `6.95293e-310` for the `GetSA` accessor function and returns a value of 200 for the side function.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You don't initialize `SA` or `V` in `Cube::Cube(double Side2)`. These may contain whatever random value that was in memory at that address.

Comment: ooooooh that makes sense, but why am i getting 200 for the GetSide Accessor?

Comment: It should be 20.0. I have no idea why it would be 200.

Comment: Figured it out it was outputting 20 there was another part that cout a 0. my bad....

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking the default constructor. It seems to initialize the data members correctly. Your parameterized constructor is only initializing the `Side` data member, and not any other data members.